# Finding shortest path between pass through a specific vertex

Tags: algorithm

I have this question
Given a directed graph G with positive edge weights and a landmark vertex x, your goal is to find the length of the shortest path from one vertex v to another vertex w that passes through the landmark x.

It is needed to Describe a O(E log V ) algorithm for the problem.
I know that the complexity of Dijkstra Algorithm is O(ElogV).

Please can you help me in how to start solving this problem.

Comment: can the same edge be visited more than once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you first find the shortest path from v to x, p_1 and from x to w, p_2 using Dijkstra's Algorithm and take the concatenation of these paths, p, then this will be the shortest path from v to w through x.

If there were a shorter path, p', then splitting this path at x would yield a path from v to x, p_1' and one from x to w, p_2' where p_1' is shorter than p_1, or p_2' is shorter than p_2 (otherwise length(p_1'+p_2') > length(p_1+p_2)) which is a contradiction.

EDIT: This is obviously O(E logV) since it is just using Dijkstra twice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: Always happy to help.