# algorithm - Path finding through a specific vertex

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, dijkstra, path-finding

I am looking for a way to find a loopless path (preferably shortest path, but not necessarily though) from a source vertex (S) to a destination vertex (D) that passes through another specific vertex (X) somewhere in the graph.

Now, before you point me to 
[Finding shortest path between pass through a specific vertex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467538/finding-shortest-path-between-pass-through-a-specific-vertex) I want to say that this solution ignores the case when the shortest path from S to X already includes D, which is a possible scenario in where I am applying this algorithm. How would you solve this problem in that case?

What I tried was a naive attempt to look for such paths in the results of Yen's K shortest paths algorithm. But I am hoping there is a more efficient and certain way to do that.

Again, just to point it out, I am not necessarily looking for the shortest path from S to D through X, but just any loopless path, although shortest path would do better.

Comment: Asking for someone to hand you an implementation is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because seeking an answer without providing an attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic concept is quite simple; then you get to adapt for cases that loop into and out of `X` on their shortest remaining paths.

- Remove `D` from the graph.
- Find `P1`, the shortest path from `S` to `X`.
- Restore `D` to the graph.
- Remove all nodes in `P1`.
- Find `P2`, the shortest path from `X` to `D`.
- return `P1` + `P2`.

That's the gist of the solution.

**NOTE**: you may find that removing `P1` yields a sub-graph with no remaining path to D.  In this case, you will want a dynamic programming solution that searches through the idea above, but with backtracking and another method to search for `P1` candidates.

When you first find `P1`, check that the node you're about to use will not isolate `X` from `D` on the second leg of the trip.  This will give you a much faster search algorithm.

Is that enough of a start?

---

The need to adapt comes from a case such as this --
consider the graph

```
src  dst
 S    1, 2
 1    X, D
 2    D
 X    1
```

Your partial paths are

```
S -> 1 -> X
S -> 2 -> 3 -> X
X -> 1 -> D
and, incidentally,
S -> 1 -> D
```

When you run your shortest-path searches, you get the path `S 1 X 1 D`, rejected because of the loop.  When you implement my first modification -- remove node `1` when trying to find a path `X to D`, there is no remaining path.

The algorithm needs the ability to back up, rejecting the path `X 1 D` to find `X 2 3 D`.  That's the coding that isn't immediately obvious from the description.

Here's a mental exercise for you: is it possible to construct a graph in which *each* shortest path (`S to X` and `X to D`) isolates the other terminal node from `X`?  In my example above, you can simply switch the process: when the `S to X` path isolates `D`, then start over: first find `X to D`, remove node `1`, and *then* find `S to X` in the remaining graph.
Can you find a graph where this switch doesn't work, either?

If not, you have an immediate solution.  If so, you have a more complex case to handle.